Past Simple for a single/habitat/repeatable event
I would like to ask about meaning of following sentence and whether it has an indication of described event being repeatable action (habit), a single one that happened just once, or whether the sentence in this tense itself has any implication of the action being a single event or repeatable habit.
The sentence:
"The plane flew out of Munich before."
By reading that sentence, can we judge whether the author implied that it was a habit/repeatable event that the plane flew out of Munich or whether was it just a single event?
Has the word "before" anything to do with the meaning of it sentence and how to understand it?
My collague was describing a history of a particular aircraft. I asked him "Was it flying out of Munich for it's transcontinental flights, or was it flying out of other international airports, according to what you know or heard about it?". Then he replied: "I know it flew out of Munich before but it could have flown from anywhere. I saw it over Portugal.". That is the context.

You mean habit, not habitat (a place an animal/insect lives). Please look up before in a dictionary. Thanks.

On its own, with no context, it's unclear what the sentence means. Did the plane leave before something else happened, or was it not the first time it had flown out of Munich?

My collague was describing a history of a particular aircraft. I asked him "Was it flying out of Munich for it's transcontinental flights, or was it flying out of other international airports, according to what you know or heard about it?".  Then he replied: "I know it flew out of Munich before but it could have flown from anywhere. I saw it over Portugal.". That is the context.

In that case - no, I don't think you can be sure whether the plane had taken off from Munich on one previous occasion, or several.

Next day I asked him the following sentence:
Me: "By saying that this aircraft flew out of Munich before and you saw it over Portugal, did you mean that it's regular airport (at the time you saw it) was Munich and it was deployed temporarily to some temporary airport thus you said it could have flown from anywhere, or did you want to say that it used to fly out of Munich just sometime in the past at some point?"
He answered: "I know it flew out of Munich once. But I don't know where it's regular airport was. Makes sense it would be in Munich.".      How to understand it?

When before is not complemented, its meaning often is "in the past", so that

The plane flew out of Munich before.

could be paraphrased

The plane used to fly (exclusively) out of Munich.

or

Munich was one of the places it used to fly out of.

Here are some examples of possible complements for before (not intended to be an exhaustive list):

... before the war
... before noon.
... before anyone sees it.
... before the airline was sold to TWA.

It is always possible that a speaker will have something like the TWA example in mind when they say or write something.  They have a specific meaning or fact in mind but don't actually utter it.
